# How to define specific Json schema in PySpark to ingest data into Kafka

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to **insert** data into **Kafka** with the schema and payload structure as required in Kafka with JSON Serialization according to org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.

The structure should be like

```
{
    "schema":
    {
        "type":"struct",
        "fields":[
            {
                "type":"string",
                "optional":true,
                "field":"username"
            },
            {
                "type":"int64",
                "optional":true,
                "name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
                "version":1,
                "field":"login_time"
            }
        ],
        "optional":false,
        "name":"login"
    },
    "payload":
        {
            "username":"myNameIsName",
            "login_time":1574333743000
        }
    }
```

I am using **Spark Structured Streaming** so the payload (the data) comes from a *streaming data frame*. So I need to put my data from the DataFrame into the schema-payload structure so that the Json is well formed and ingested correctly into Kafka. The final target is ElasticSearch.

I believe that the problem would be resolve if I build the JSON from a DataFrame as requested with the schema shown above.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Are you using Spark Structured Streaming just to make well form JSON?

Comment: no, I am processing data, some aggregations and joins with other tables but the final result should be sent back to Kafka with the specific Json structured so that it can be sent to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Kafka Connect schemas don't translate directly to Spark schemas. You need to define the schema yourself, as other SparkSQL + JSON examples show.

Comment: The most obvious seems `DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch` where you'd have to do the JSON conversation yourself. You could use `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` as part of the conversion.

Comment: agree, what I am trying to do is to define the schema with `StructField` and `StructType` and then using `to_json()` function and passing the schema to it but it is not working. The target is to ingest aggregated data to ElasticSearch.